# Azure machine learning designer - edit columns stuck on loading

Tags: azure, machine-learning, designer

I have a dataset on the Azure ML designer connected to a Normalize data module but it keeps loading when i try to Edit columns on Normalize data module with no result or errors.
The same thing happens with Select columns in dataset module or any other dataset.

I have tried on both Mac and Windows with different browsers and recreated, restarted and even deleted the whole resource group but still getting stuck on loading.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

[Edit columns stuck on this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ccdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug that currently is being worked on by Microsoft team.

[Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/343332/azure-machine-learning-designer-edit-columns-stuck.html?childToView=343506#comment-343506)